# new window/view mxml flex

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

I have the following problem of how to display another mxml file as main view of application

For example, lets say I have `main.mxml` displaying as main window. When I click button I want to display another mxml file lets say `newMain.mxml` and close `main.mxml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by using NativeWindow Class in Adobe AIR.

You can create native window and can activate it.
While activating your newMain.mxml into another native window you can set your main.mxml to visible false.

And when closing your newMain.mxml you can set main.mxml to visible true.

I am giving some sample Flex 4.5 Application Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var n:NativeWindow;
            private var ni:NativeWindowInitOptions;

            protected function onBtnOpenClick(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                ni = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
                ni.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
                ni.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
                ni.transparent = false;
                ni.resizable = false;
                ni.minimizable = true;
                ni.maximizable = true;

                n = new NativeWindow(ni);
                n.title = "My Native Window";
                n.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING, onClosingWindowEvent);
                n.activate();

                nativeWindow.visible = false;
            }

            private function onClosingWindowEvent(event:Event):void
            {
                nativeWindow.visible = true;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button x="217" y="110" label="Open" click="onBtnOpenClick(event)"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```